# Functional solution for looping through nested dictionaries

Tags: python, functional-programming

I have a dictionary of which keys are strings, and its values dictionaries. The depth is defined and constant: 3. When I need to loop through it, I do the following:

```
for k1, v1 in d1.iteritems():
  for k2, v2 in v1.iteritems():
    for k3, v3 in v2.iteritems():
      # Do something with k1, k2, k3 and v3
```

I would like to know if there is a cleaner functional solution (without defining it myself), so that I could do something like this:

```
for k1, k2, k3, v3 in superfunction(d1):
  # Do something...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i.e. a built-in one? Writing `superfunction` yourself is fairly straight-forward.

Comment: There is no built-in for this.

Comment: A built-in I guess not, but something in a standard library, or a well known third-party library.

Comment: I was including the standard library, and I am not aware of a third-party library implementing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want very tight code you can use list comprehensions:

```
d={"A":{"B":{"C":"FOO"}}}
[(k1,k2,k3,v3) for k1,v1 in  d.items() for k2,v2 in v.items() for k3,v3 in v1.items()]
```

But I'm not sure that that is significantly better than what you're doing.

Comment: Nevertheless, it's functional and does what I want. Thanks.

Comment: @ikaros45 you should be careful with *"functional"* - it has a [specific meaning in programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) (and this isn't it).

Comment: @jonrsharpe You're probably right, but well... comprehensions are still considered part of FP, in contrast to the the imperative solution of defining a container and filling it out in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a try at implementing an iterator that does it. It was a bit more complicated than I thought it would be, but it works, and for an arbitrary level:

```
def superiter(d, l, cur = None):
    if cur is None:
        cur = [[]]
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        if l == 1:
            cur[0].extend((k, v))
            yield cur[0]
            cur[0] = cur[0][:-2]
        else:
            cur[0].append(k)
            for x in superiter(v, l-1, cur):
                yield x
            cur[0] = cur[0][:-1]


In [112]: d1 = {1:{2:{3:4, 5:6}}, 10:{7:{8:9}}}

In [113]: for k1, k2, k3, v in superiter(d1, 3):
     ...:     print k1, ' ', k2, ' ', k3, ' ', v
     ...:     
1   2   3   4
1   2   5   6
10   7   8   9

In [114]: d2 = {1:{2:3, 4:5}, 6:{7:8}}

In [115]: for k1, k2, v in superiter(d2, 2):
     ...:     print k1, ' ', k2, ' ', v
     ...:     
1   2   3
1   4   5
6   7   8
```

and it's easy enough to make it work for nested dictionaries with varying depth:

```
def superiter(d, cur = None):
    if cur is None:
        cur = [[]]
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        if not isinstance(v, dict):
            cur[0].extend((k, v))
            yield cur[0]
            cur[0] = cur[0][:-2]
        else:
            cur[0].append(k)
            for x in superiter(v, cur):
                yield x
            cur[0] = cur[0][:-1]


In [120]: d1 = {1:{2:{3:4, 5:6}, 10:{7:{8:9}}}}

In [121]: list(superiter(d1))
Out[121]: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 5, 6], [1, 10, 7, 8, 9]]
```